# Don't show comment pop-up on locked posts

Tags: bug, comments, locked-questions

When you click the downvote arrow on a post which is comment locked, the banner saying to consider commenting still appears.  Obviously, you can't comment on a comment-locked post.

[image]

Comment: Well, it's consistent with many other things in SE. For example, we can click "delete" just to get alert "You have already voted to delete", we can click the award bounty link just to be greeted with "You can award bounty in 20 hours", etc.

Comment: Yeah, similar... except in those cases it's explaining why you can't do what you're attempting to do, not telling you to do something that you can't.